# Formatted Printing:Boolean Issue

Tags: python

The purpose of this piece of code is to take in a string and print it out in a specific format. For instance, given:

```
s = "Hello"
```

The program should print out:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| H | e | l | l | o |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If the size of the string is greater than the column size of the console, it's then supposed to print out the string in this format:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| H | e | l | l | o |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| H | e | l | l | o |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| H | e | l | l | o |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| H | e | l | l | o |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Unfortunately, the second condition doesn't work and I can't seem to figure out why.

Here's my code:

```
import os

s = "Hello"*20
(consoleRows,consoleCol)=os.popen('stty size','r').read().split()
top = outer = "+---"*len(s)+'+'+'\n'
for i in range(len(s)):
    outer += "| "+s[i]+" "

outer += '|\n'
outer += top[:len(top)-1]

split = outer.split('\n')
if(len(split[0]) > consoleCol): #problem lies on this line. Even though the size of  
    outer = outer.split('\n') #split[0] is greater than consoleCol the if statement  
    beg = 0   #isn't entered.                                                        
    size = consoleCol
    print(outer[0][beg:size])
    while(size < len(outer[0])):
        print(outer[1][beg:size]);
        print(outer[2][beg:size]);
        beg = size
        size += size
else:
    print(outer)
```

Can anyone see what my problem is? I printed out the size of outer[0] and of consoleCol. len(output[0]) is greater than consoleCol.

Comment: You may want to replace the call to `os.popen()` with one to `os.get_terminal_size()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug in the code: consoleCol is a string, not an integer.

Replace `(consoleRows,consoleCol)=os.popen('stty size','r').read().split()` with 
`(consoleRows,consoleCol)=map(int, os.popen('stty size','r').read().split())`

This still doesn't produce the desired result - you'll have to figure the rest out yourself and maybe clean up the code in the process.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'm no python guy. That said, I would recommend to separate the logic from your layout. Create methods `drawHorizontalLine`, `drawContentLine(Char[5])` and `Char[5][] splitContent(String)`. Afterwards debugging should be easy.